# How would I get the preprocessed configuration of an LXC guest?

Tags: configuration, lxc

So LXC is installed, guests configured and working, but how would I extract information from the *effective* LXC configuration of a single guest?

Now the naive approach is obvious. Take the output of `$(lxc-config lxc.lxcpath)`, append the name of the guest plus `config` and read that. I.e.:

```
$(lxc-config lxc.lxcpath)/guestname/config
```

however, there's a little problem with this approach.

For starters it doesn't account for `/etc/lxc/lxc.conf` or `/etc/lxc/default.conf`, but it also doesn't take into account includes (`lxc.include`).

This poses a problem. Unless I start reinventing the wheel to get the semantics right, there appears to be no way for me to extract the effective guest configuration after preprocessing. That is: after the full hierarchy of configuration files has been parsed *in order*, includes have been inserted and so on.

So **how** would I go about to **extract the effective LXC guest configuration** while observing the **same semantics** the LXC configuration file parser uses?